# Sum Formatted Amount Money in Javascript return NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

i'm having an array of string with in currency format for each array value:

```
var sells = ['INR1,433,200.00','INR5,750.00','INR12,000.00','INR1,905.00','INR235.00'];
```

i try to loop through each value of this array , and sum it to get the total in currency format

```
var total = 0;
sells.forEach(function(sell) {
    total += sell;
});
console.log(total);
```

When i see the browser console log the result is always `NaN` , i expected the result to be `INR1,453,090.00`

Comment: `INR1,453,090.00`, `INR5,750.00`, etc cannot be converted to a `Number`

Comment: the issue is you are trying to add values in the array with non-number characters (INR). first, remove that then add them

Comment: you would have to remove `INR` prefix from each value from your `sells` array first and parse these values to integer, otherwise you can't sum strings like that

Comment: Try `total += +sell.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')`

Comment: I strongly suggest your array should hold simple floats and then format when you display only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You replace `INR` and the commas and cast the `String` into a `Number`:

```js
var sells = ['INR1,433,200.00','INR5,750.00','INR12,000.00','INR1,905.00','INR235.00'];

var total = 0;
sells.forEach(function(sell) {
    total += +sell.replace('INR','').replace(/,/g,'');
});
console.log(total);
```

---

You can also use `reduce`:

```js
var sells = ['INR1,433,200.00', 'INR5,750.00', 'INR12,000.00', 'INR1,905.00', 'INR235.00'];
console.log(sells.reduce((acc, val) => acc + +val.replace('INR', '').replace(/,/g, ''), 0));
```

Comment: how to reformat back the result?

Comment: @jojo It was a human being that helped you here, not a machine. At least say *"thanks"*.